# BackgroundWorker для while

Tags: c#

Подскажите подойдет ли BackgroundWorker для такой цели :

После подключение юзера выполняется данный код

```
public static void AcceptPlayer(System.Net.Sockets.Socket socket) {
    var ip = ((IPEndPoint) socket.RemoteEndPoint).Address;
    ProtectProfiles.Add(ip, new ProtectProfile(socket));
}
```

нужно чтобы после new ProtectProfile(socket) в самом классе выполнялась функция, в которой будит содержаться while() и чтобы при выполнение его не блокировался поток - net 3.5 await async нету еще в нем.
Или посоветуйте что я могу использовать как альтернитиву

Код сервера

```
private static IPEndPoint _localEndPoint;
private static TcpListener _listener;

public static Dictionary < IPAddress, ProtectProfile > ProtectProfiles = new Dictionary < IPAddress, ProtectProfile > ();

public void Awake() {
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    _localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("178.44.152.88"), server.port + 2);
    _listener = new TcpListener(_localEndPoint);
    _listener.Start();
}

public void Update() {
    if (_listener == null || !_listener.Pending()) return;
    var connect = _listener.AcceptTcpClient();
    var ip = ((IPEndPoint) connect.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address;
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Connect " + ip);
    ProtectProfile.AcceptPlayer(connect);
}
```

Профиль

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace REDUX.CORE {
    public class ProtectProfile {
        public TcpClient TcpClient;
        public ProtectProfile Profile;

        public ProtectProfile(TcpClient client) {
            Profile = this;
            TcpClient = client;
            var t = new Thread(() => Profile.GetStream()) {
                IsBackground = true
            };
            t.Start();
        }

        public void GetStream() {
            while (true) {
                var stream = TcpClient.GetStream().Length;
                switch (stream) {
                    default: Loom.QueueOnMainThread(() =>
                        Logger.Log(stream.ToString()));
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        #
        region[STATIC CLASS]

        public static Dictionary < IPAddress, ProtectProfile > ProtectProfiles =
            new Dictionary < IPAddress, ProtectProfile > ();

        public static void AcceptPlayer(TcpClient tcpClient) {
            var ip = ((IPEndPoint) tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address;
            ProtectProfiles.Add(ip, new ProtectProfile(tcpClient));
            Loom.QueueOnMainThread(() =>
                Logger.Log(ProtectProfiles.Count.ToString()));
        }

        #
        endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Как альтернативу — запустите ваш цикл в отдельном потоке, а все вызовы для интерфейса производите через Dispatcher.Invoke

Comment: Если же вы не хотите вообще блокировать поток, то используйте вместо цикла таймер

Comment: @tym32167 просто я хочу поддерживать онлайн до 50 человек.Если для каждого соединение держать отдельный поток это не сильно нагрузить машину?

Comment: Если на Pentium 1 будете держать сервер, то да, 50 пользователей создадут хорошую нагрузку. А можно увидеть чуть больше кода вашего сервера? Насколько я правильно понял вы показали вызываемый метод при получении нового подключения.

Comment: @Rootware прикрепил к теме - кстати не можете подсказать как 'задетектить' получение стримов - нужно для получение и обработки данных в GetStream

Comment: @tym32167 ну или вы можете подсказать по поводу детекта получение стримов?

Comment: Я вам могу привести в пример другую модель слушателя, клиента и стрим обработчика. Естественно, это будет каркас. Нужное допишите сами. Но то что у вас непонятно мне. Извините.

Comment: @Rootware приведите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример примитивного сервера для обработки входящий соединений от клиентов.

**ClientSocketListener** - открываем сокет и обрабатываем все входящие подключения

```
public sealed class ClientSocketListener
{
    private static volatile ClientSocketListener INSTANCE;
    private static object syncRoot = new Object();

    private TcpListener _listener;
    private Thread _thread;

    private ClientSocketListener()
    {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    public void run()
    {
        _listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Config.CLIENT_PORT);
        _listener.Start();

        _thread = new Thread(AwaitClientConnection);
        _thread.IsBackground = true;
        _thread.Start();
    }

    private void AwaitClientConnection()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (_listener.Pending())
            {
                TcpClient clientSocket = _listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                accept(clientSocket);
            }
        }
    }

    private void accept(TcpClient tcpClient)
    {
        LoginClient client = new LoginClient(tcpClient);
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        _thread.Abort();
        _listener.Stop();
    }

    public static ClientSocketListener getInstance
    {
        get
        {
            if (INSTANCE == null)
            {
                lock (syncRoot)
                {
                    if (INSTANCE == null)
                        INSTANCE = new ClientSocketListener();
                }
            }

            return INSTANCE;
        }
    }
}
```

LoginClient - создаём клиента и обрабатываем все его соединения.

```
public class LoginClient
{
    protected TcpClient _client;

    public NetworkStream _stream;

    private byte[] _buffer;

    public EndPoint _address;

    public LoginClient(TcpClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
        _stream = client.GetStream();
        _address = client.Client.RemoteEndPoint;

        new Thread(read).Start();
    }

    public void read()
    {
        try
        {
            _buffer = new byte[2];
            _stream.BeginRead(_buffer, 0, 2, new AsyncCallback(OnReceiveCallbackStatic), null);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            _client.Close();
        }
    }

    private void OnReceiveCallbackStatic(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_stream.EndRead(result) > 0)
            {
                short Length = BitConverter.ToInt16(_buffer, 0);
                _buffer = new byte[Length - 2];
                _stream.BeginRead(_buffer, 0, Length - 2, new AsyncCallback(OnReceiveCallback), result.AsyncState);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _client.Close();
        }
    }

    private void OnReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        _stream.EndRead(result);

        byte[] buff = new byte[_buffer.Length];
        _buffer.CopyTo(buff, 0);

        byte[] packet = new byte[buff.Length - 1];
        Array.Copy(buff, 1, packet, 0, packet.Length);

        // Отправка содержимого буфера в обработчик пакетов
        ClientPacketHandler.handlePacket(this, buff[0], packet);

        new System.Threading.Thread(read).Start();
    }
}
```

Инициализация слушателя

```
ClientSocketListener.getInstance.run();
```

Остановка слушателя

```
ClientSocketListener.getInstance.stop();
```

Обработчик буфера и отправку ответа допишите сами. В `LoginClient` классе можете создавать любые иные фоновые потоки по желанию. Они будут относиться именно к этому клиенту.

Метод обработки пакетов (пример):

```
public static LoginClientPacket handlePacket(LoginClient client, byte opcode, byte[] data)
{
    LoginClientPacket msg = null;
    switch (opcode)
    {
        case 0x00:
            msg = new RecieveAuth(client, data);
            break;

        default:
            _log.info("Unknown packet opcode: 0x" + opcode.ToString("X2"));
            break;
    }

    return msg;
}
```

Список подключений не создавал. Не было необходимости.

Нагрузка на 200-300 подключений не проверял в C# реализации, но данная модель в Java держит гораздо больше, чем 50 человек.

P.S. если есть замечания по реализации, то с радостью выслушаю.

Comment: @Rootwake а где мне здесь можно добавить switch?Отправляемые пакеты с сервера у меня просто идут по enum флагам

Comment: @Алексей создайте хэдлер и отправляйте в него данные. А там вставите свой switch. В моём примере switch находится в `ClientPacketHandler.handlePacket(this, buff[0], packet);`. Ответ обновил.

Comment: @RootWake net 3.5 по поводу ClientPacketHandler молчит - нету такого видимо - с хандлами не работал еще

Comment: @Алексей `Handler` - это в переводе означает обработчик чего либо. Такие методы/классы не присутствуют в `.Net` - их пишут руками для обработки однотипных заданий.

Comment: случаем не delegate и event?

Comment: Если вам нужно что-то проще, то можете почитать вот [это](https://metanit.com/sharp/net/3.2.php).

Comment: если вы имеете ввиду delegate и event то ими я пользоваться умею )

Comment: Нет. В этой реализации нет этого. Тут примитивная логика и не требует делагатов, т.к. нет обращений к иным потокам. А из основного слушателя можно с лёгкостью обращаться к любому клиенту, если их коллекционировать в список.

Comment: тогда я не пойму что за handle такие и как их использовать

Comment: Хэдлер (Handler) - это просто обработчик каких-либо однотипных данных. Просто так принято этот класс/метод называть для удобства чтения кода. Никакой скрытой магии в этом слове больше нет.

Comment: а в OnReceiveCallback перед созданием нового потока этот не нужно закрывать?Не вызовет лагов если не закрыть?

Comment: что-то не понял как принимать стримы - вот так переписал,но файл для теста не передается :( https://pastebin.com/2xsaw99Y

Comment: _stream.Read(params ...) - читаем из потока входящие данные, _stream.Write(params ...) - пишем в поток исходящие данные, _stream.Flush() - очищаем поток после записи. У вас вообще ересь. Вы пишите в файл.

Comment: Мне для теста и нужно записать в файл "This is some text in the file." -  сейчас только увидил,что отправка с клиента на сервер простого текста "this is a test" занимает более 1 минуты